# sed or awk with multiple conditions

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some files looking like this

```
define host{
            use                             gen-host
            host_name                       AA1234
            ......
            }

define service{
            use                             gen-perf,gen-infra,gen-svc
            host_name                       AA1234
            service_description             check1
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }

define service{
            use                             gen-svc
            host_name                       AA1234
            service_description             check2
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }

define service{
            use                             gen-appli,gen-svc
            host_name                       AA1234
            service_description             check3
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }

define service{
            use                             gen-perf,gen-svc
            host_name                       AA1234
            service_description             check4
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }

define service{
            use                             gen-appli,gen-svc
            host_name                       AA1234
            service_description             check5
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }
```

I want to parse each file, and for each stanza between define **service{** and **}** do something like this :

- If I found on the line *service_description* a keywork (listed in another file used as reference), I want to check that gen-infra exists on the line *use*, otherwise I need to add it just before gen-svc.
- If on the line *service_description*, I don't find one of the listed keyword, and if *gen-appli* doesn't exist on the line *use*, add it !

Example :

If I find *check2*, I should add gen-infra if not present so the stanza above should be

```
define service{
            use                             gen-infra,gen-svc
            host_name                       AA1234
            service_description             check2
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }
```

*check4* is not in the reference list, so I should add gen-appli if not present so the stanza above should be

```
define service{
            use                             gen-perf,gen-appli,gen-svc
            host_name                       AA1234
            service_description             check4
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }
```

With sed, I managed to add *gen-infra* if I find one of the listed keyword and add *gen-appli* if I don't find any.

```
sed -i "/define service/,/}/{H;d;};x;/service_description\s*${INFRA_LST}/! s/use\s*\([[:graph:]]*\)\(gen-svc\)\(.*\)/use\t\t\t\t\1gen-appli,\2\3/g" FILE_TO_PARSE.txt
sed -i "/define service/,/}/{H;d;};x;/service_description\s*${INFRA_LST}/ s/use\s*\([[:graph:]]*\)\(gen-svc\)\(.*\)/use\t\t\t\t\1gen-infra,\2\3/g" FILE_TO_PARSE.txt
```

${INFRA_LST} containing the list of keywords based on the refence file.
${INFRA_LST} looks as below (with a lot more keywords of course) :

```
service_description[[:blank:]]*check2\|service_description[[:blank:]]*check10
```

In the real life, I can have others things than gen-svc, so that explains the group as I there a OR condition in there.

But how to add a 2nd condition to do this **only** if *gen-infra* or *gen-appli* are not already present ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show us how the reference file looks like?

Comment: As I said, it's a simple txt file with 1 keyword by line then I generate the ${INFRA_LST} variable with it. I edited my original post.

Comment: IMHO, `sed` is the wrong tool for this. It lends itself to `Perl`, or maybe `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in bash.
`sed` is a simple good tool to parse lines, for multi-line parsing it's simpler to use a proper language.
Script rules were:

1. If in a service the `service_description` tag is equal to the string `check2`, the program should add the name `gen-infra` to the `use` tag.
2. If in a service the `service_description` tag is not equal to the string `check4`, the program should add the name `gen-appli` to the `use` tag.
3. The order of the names in the `use` tag does not matter and are separated by `,` commas.
4. The tag `use` has at least one name in it already.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

assert() { if ! eval "$1"; then echo "Assertion '$1' failed!" >&2; exit 1; fi; }

add_name_to_use() {
    local service name
    service=$1
    name=$2
    sed '/^[[:space:]]*use[[:space:]]*/{/'"$name"'/b;s/$/,'"$name"'/}' <<<"$service"
}

cmp_service_description() {
    local service value
    service=$1
    shift
    greparg='^[[:space:]]*service_description[[:space:]]*\('
    for i; do
        greparg+="$i\\|"
    done
    greparg=$(sed 's/\\|$//'<<<"$greparg")
    greparg+='\)$'
    grep -q "$greparg" <<<"$service"
}

handle_one_service() {
    local service
    service=$1
    # If I find check2,
    if cmp_service_description "$service" "check2" "keyword2" "and so on..."; then
        # I should add gen-infra if not present
        service=$(add_name_to_use "$service" "gen-infra")
    fi
    # if check4 is not in the reference list
    if ! cmp_service_description "$service" "check4"; then
        # I should add gen-appli
        service=$(add_name_to_use "$service" "gen-appli")
    fi
    echo "$service"
}

inservice=false
str=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
    str+="$line"$'\n'
    case "$line" in
    "define service{")
        inservice=true
        ;;
    *"}"*)
        if "$inservice"; then
            inservice=false
            handle_one_service "$str"
        else
            echo "$str"
        fi
        str=""
        ;;
    esac
done
```

I have written the function `cmp_service_description` so you can check for a multiple (a list) of values.
The output compared with the input column wise. On the left the original file, on the right the script output:

```
$ paste -d'#' 1 <(./parse.sh <1) | column -t -s'#' -o' | '
define host{                                                           | define host{
            use                             gen-host                   |             use                             gen-host
            host_name                       AA1234                     |             host_name                       AA1234
            ......                                                     |             ......
            }                                                          |             }
                                                                       | 
define service{                                                        | 
            use                             gen-perf,gen-infra,gen-svc | define service{
            host_name                       AA1234                     |             use                             gen-perf,gen-infra,gen-svc,gen-appli
            service_description             check1                     |             host_name                       AA1234
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             service_description             check1
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }                                                          |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                                                                       |             }
define service{                                                        | 
            use                             gen-svc                    | define service{
            host_name                       AA1234                     |             use                             gen-svc,gen-infra,gen-appli
            service_description             check2                     |             host_name                       AA1234
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             service_description             check2
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }                                                          |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                                                                       |             }
define service{                                                        | 
            use                             gen-appli,gen-svc          | define service{
            host_name                       AA1234                     |             use                             gen-appli,gen-svc
            service_description             check3                     |             host_name                       AA1234
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             service_description             check3
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }                                                          |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                                                                       |             }
define service{                                                        | 
            use                             gen-perf,gen-svc           | define service{
            host_name                       AA1234                     |             use                             gen-perf,gen-svc
            service_description             check4                     |             host_name                       AA1234
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             service_description             check4
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }                                                          |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                                                                       |             }
define service{                                                        | 
            use                             gen-appli,gen-svc          | 
            host_name                       AA1234                     | define service{
            service_description             check5                     |             use                             gen-appli,gen-svc
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             host_name                       AA1234
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy            |             service_description             check5
            }                                                          |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                                                                       |             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                                                                       |             }
```

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 are incorrects
The reference file contains a lot of strings to test (ex : check2 is in it / check4 is NOT).
If the stanza **contains** one of the reference string (ex : check1, check2), check that **gen-infra** exists. Otherwise it needs to be added **just before gen-svc**.
If the stanza **doesn't contain** one of the reference string (ex : check4), check that **gen-appli** exists. Otherwise it needs to be added **just before gen-svc**